# Get user IP with ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

My rails app works with nginx and unicorn. I try used

```
Socket.ip_address_list 
request.ip
```

without success... How I can get user IP?

**UPDATE**
I fix it by adding in host configutation

```
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

and use

```
request.remote_ip
```

Answer (score 0):

`request.remote_ip` should work.

HTH